# Table of contents language update

Tags: table-of-contents, babel

I am writing an article in dutch, so I have changed (using `\renewcommand`) the language of my tables, toc, figures and appendices. However, my table of contents won't update to the new language. This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\addto\captionsdutch{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Bijlagen}%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhoudsopgave}%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figuur}
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabel}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

This is a sample document

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Title 1}

text here

\newpage
\section{Title 2}

text here

\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\section{Number one}
\label{appendix:numberone}
\newpage

\section{Number two}
\label{appendix:numbertwo}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The sections are ofcourse already in dutch and using the `\contentsname` macro, the title of the toc did change to "Inhoudsopgave". Also, In the actual appendices at the end of my document, it says "Bijlagen". So I don't understand why my toc does not update as well.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.tex. With documentclass `article` the TOC title is named _Inhoudsopgave_. What `\documentclass{}` are you using?

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{10pt}{article}`

Comment: Do you really have curly braces `{}` around the `10pt`? That should give all sorts of errors. It should be `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` with square brackets. Please complete your code to a fully compilable document (what we call a minimal working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and show us a picture of the output of that exact code compiled on your machine.

Comment: owh, that was a typo, i have "[]" in my code

Comment: With `article` I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe, you can update your question and provide us an image of what you desire?

Comment: OK good. If you had had `{}` in your real document you should have realised that (you should have gotten lots of errors and complaints). Still, please complete the code you have shown us so far to a compilable document and show us the output you get (see second half of my last comment). I have just looked up the definitions of `babel-dutch` and by default `\contentsname`, `\figurename` and `\tablename` are already as desired. Only `\appendixpagename` but there is `\appendixname` which is `B"ylage`

Comment: this is my current toc. But I want "Appendices" to be named "Bijlagen, the weird thing is, that at the bottom of my document it says "Bijlagen"

Comment: *Please* make your code compilable.

Comment: wait, one more thing

Comment: This is it, hope this helps

Comment: Yes that helped very much. It is so much easier for us to help you if the code shown in the question is compilable. Let me know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `appendix` defines and uses two new appendix name strings `\appendixtocname` for the table of contents and `\appendixpagename` for the appendix page. Just redefine these two strings and you will be good. Note that you do not have to redefine `\contentsname`, `\figurename` and `tablename`: they already have the definition you want.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\addto\captionsdutch{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Bijlagen}%
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Bijlagen}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

This is a sample document

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Title 1}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Lalala}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Lalala}
\end{table}

text here

\newpage
\section{Title 2}

text here

\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\section{Number one}
\label{appendix:numberone}
\newpage

\section{Number two}
\label{appendix:numbertwo}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC page of the example document showing the heading "Inhoudsopgave" and entries: 1 Title 1 2//2 Title 2 3//Bijlagen 4//A Number one 4//B Number two 5]

Comment: It did indeed solve the problem. Thank you so much! Next time I will indeed add the compilable code (still a rookie ;) )